# Hitting times for a random walk on a square

Tags: markov-chains, random-walk

Let $ABCD$ be a square and  {$X_t, t \in \mathbb{N}$}  a discrete random walk on this square (i.e the state space is {$A,B,C,D$}). Let

$$\tau_D := \min\{ t\geq0 : X_t = D \}$$ and
$$\tau_C := \min\{ t\geq0 : X_t = C \}$$

How to calculate:

$$P_x(\tau_C \leq s \cap \tau_C > \tau_D )$$, where $s \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in$ {$A,B,C,D$}
and $P_x(.) = P(.|X_0 = x)$

My attempt was:
$$P_x(\tau_C \leq s \cap \tau_C > \tau_D ) = P_x(\tau_C \leq s | \tau_C > \tau_D )P_x(\tau_C > \tau_D)$$

But I can't find a way to continue after it.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  If $t\in \mathbb N$, shouldn't the "inf" just be a "min"?  And...are you walking on the boundary of the square only (so that the only possible positions are the corners)?   Something else? And...what is $x$?  And...where does the walk start?

Comment: I edited the question, x is the starting point, so $P_x(.)$ is the probability of . given that we started at $x$. You are right, the walk can only be done on the boundary and inf can be seen as min.

Comment: I suggest editing for clarity.  $x$ is not defined in your problem, why use "inf" and talk about "$t≥0$" when in fact $t\in \mathbb N$ and you just have an ordinary min?  And include some effort.  Some of the possible starting points are easier to analyze than others.

Comment: Sorry. Now I perceived the fact that I used the vraible $t$ indistinctly. I will re-edit the question to clarify.